# How to insert listGrid data into a pie chart C#

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MedC.png)

I'm having this difficulty getting the Category column values ​​and putting them on the chart where it is repeating category 3x, category and credit card should appear, and the graph will appear how many times these values ​​were entered (category and credit card)

Can someone help me?

```
public void Grafico()
{
    Series pie = chart1.Series.Add("pie");
    pie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
    pie.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

    for (int colindex = 1; colindex < ListaGrid.Columns.Count; colindex++)
    {
        s.Points.AddXY(ListaGrid.Columns[2].HeaderText,
        ListaGrid[columnIndex, 2].Value);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Tg0A.png)

I'm trying to make it look like this in the picture
obg